# Help with major software issues after unlicensed windows 7 install over Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, dell

I am overseas right now and purchased a new Dell laptop that was supposed to have Ubuntu installed, it has the Ubuntu sticker I was told the product does not have recovery CDs.

Anyway I am not familiar with Ubuntu and did not even know about the operating system so I asked if they could install windows 7. I found out it's not a licensed windows 7 and I have been going nuts trying to install a bunch of drivers and stuff just to get things working right, everything is running so slow.

I am wondering if them installing windows is the cause of all the driver and other problems,and if reinstalling Ubuntu will fix them? If so where do I reinstall it since I don't have a CD of the program?

Please help I am getting so frustrated. The place I got it from is not a major store just a kind of backstreet place,so I need to figure this out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

When you buy a computer with Ubuntu pre-installed you either get a DVD with the operating system on it, or it will be on a recovery partition or you are told to [download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) it yourself and burn the download to a DVD. The last option works if you have a system with an internet connection and a DVD burner. The one before that works but you need to check your hard disk if there is a recovery partition and figure out what keys you need to press during boot to get it activated.

Computers with Ubuntu pre-installed are generally NOT sold with a Windows license. Ubuntu can run on very old hardware. A machine that is sold with Ubuntu might have hardware in it that Microsoft does not support or no longer supports so Windows 7 is not possible to run on it (Microsoft would like you to buy the newest hardware to run their latest product)

So yes, your problems will fix itself if you re-install Ubuntu. You might also get a working machine installing an older Microsoft product (like Windows XP. I am not saying that an obsolete operating system is a good option though).